# iTunes In app purchase

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, cordova

I am going to develop an iphone application which involves in app purchase. 
So i would like to know the advantages and disadvantages using apple itunes in app purchase over other payment methods like **paypal**

Please let me know your comments
thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Uh... for in app purchase you HAVE to use iTunes.  If you use something else Apple will reject your application.  See Section 11.2 of the [Developer Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html).

Comment: @matt: thanks for the reply and what about using phone gap and integrate wuth any of the payment gateways

Comment: This should work to integrate it with in app purchase  https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iPhone/InAppPurchaseManager

Comment: All of the above applies to virtual goods only. There is nothing preventing you from selling a car, house or a packet of cornflakes using the payment service of your choice.