# Apple Itunes In-App purchases and alternatives

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, itunes-store

We have hit a hurdle with Apple/Itunes and rejection of a submitted binary and would like to know how to find a solution which meets the 'guidelines' and also fits our purpose.

We have 2 billing situations (Subscription for services outside the app):

1. Subscription (monthly or annually) - Can use In-App Purchase but how does an external system view each transaction or status (eg a website using API to extract?)
2. Variable priced monthly fee - Monthly subscription + varying additional fee based on usage (similar to a post pay mobile phone plan)

Therefore, 2 questions:

1. How does an external source (eg a webserver) extract InApp purchase data for a specific user?
2. Can In-App purchases perform variable priced subscriptions, (similar to ReferenceTransaction in Paypal or a BillingProfile/Authorize process for payment gateways)

I'm not familiar with PhoneGap and the Approval process this would require but would assume the same problem would occure with Apple stating the guidelines are being breached.

> Ideally we would like to use PayPal for Subscriptions and PayPal/Local
>   Payment Gateway for CreditCard authorisation billing of variable
>   monthly amounts. The framework to technically perform this is
>   available via customised API calls.
>
> If InApp purchases can perform these functions and present a summary of this information to an external service we're happy to work with Apple but so far I cannot find anything that would suggest the functionality is available.

Any information related to Payments within an IOS App would be appreciated.

We've been told that if we do not use InApp purchases we must remove ANY links to the website and not have a registration section within the App, only login.

Found these links below which do not inspire much confidence:

[How to sync iphone in-app purchase with website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43717137/how-to-sync-iphone-in-app-purchase-with-website)

[iTunes In app purchase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8381524/itunes-in-app-purchase)

Answer (score 0):

For any in-app purchase review guidelines. Refer to this [link](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#subscriptions)

Q1. How does an external source (eg a webserver) extract InApp purchase data for a specific user?
-> Make sure you use a secure server (https not http) to access receipts. Refer to this link for [Validating Receipts with Secure Server](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010573-CH105-SW1)

Refer to sample and Video series showing example of validating on server [RayWenerlinch ( External Website )](https://www.raywenderlich.com/122144/in-app-purchase-tutorial)

Q2. Can In-App purchases perform variable priced subscriptions, (similar to ReferenceTransaction in Paypal or a BillingProfile/Authorize process for payment gateways)

-> Yes, you can add new in-app purchases and subscriptions without adding new build. [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnectInAppPurchase_Guide/Chapters/SubmittingInAppPurchases.html)

Comment: Thank you for the post. 
Regarding set price subscriptions - Seems possible. 
Regarding variable price bill - Can a server initial an in-app purchase? Sounds strange if so? The amounts to be billed would be calculated monthly on the central server so I cannot see how this would be possible... I'll review further and ask around a bit more. Thank you for your comments

Comment: @JI-Web - it's possible. You can have predefined set of in-app subscriptions created and have a server calculate and return required in-app id at runtime. However you need to create required combinations in itunes manually.